# open android application using url and go to different screen

Tags: android

how to start my app using a url link and go to different activity. i have used this code

```
<activity
            android:name=".Act1"
            android:label="activity first"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="xyz.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/abc/"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

by using this code i am able to open Act1 while entering into my android app but i want to switch to Act2 and Act3. because i have to use three different url and for all the stating screen should be Act1, Act2 and Act3 as click on url1, url2 and url3 respectively. please suggest if any solution.

Comment: why don't you have different path prefixes to Act2 & Act3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best things to do is to launch the same activity ("Front activity"). In this "front activity" you parse the url and launch Act1, 2, 3 depending on the url.

Comment: how to get data if first link redirected to another.. for example if i start my application to link as... "https://abcd/def/ggj=2/anjs.php" and this link ridirected to "jhkl://xyscf/def/ggj=1/anjs1.php" now how can i get the data of second link in my java file

Comment: You will need to run the request in your application to get the redirection.